# Tool to determine if all Java bytecode dependencies are properly met

Tags: java, dependencies

Is there any tool that, given a set of jars (and/or class files, possibly plus java source), reports when any Java bytecode dependencies fail (e.g., missing types, methods, constructors, and/or fields)?

Obviously, a compiler does this for source, but I want it for bytecode.

`jdeps` seems to only work for class and/or packages, not for class members.

I want this tool to ensure that jars of mine are at least binary signature compatible with multiple versions of third-party jars.  I only compile against the newest supported versions of the jars, but if an older version of a jar isn't binary compatible, then I know that it can't work for all code paths in my code.  Obviously, binary compatibility doesn't guarantee correctness, but at least it identifies certain incompatibilities.

Answer (score 0):

It probably does not do exactly what you want but have a look at [bnd](https://bnd.bndtools.org/).

It does deep byte code inspection to generate metadata for modular (OSGi) jars which may be of use to you. For example its [Baselining](https://bnd.bndtools.org/chapters/180-baselining.html) sounds somewhat similar to what you describe. Perhaps you may extend it or build on top of it to cover your usecase.

Comment: Thanks for info.  I'll look into bnd later.  I've appended my use case to the question.